# UINavigationItem with titleview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

In my app i have a `UINavigationController`. and i want to add method that when the user press the navigation something will happen.so i add a button `titleview`:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.titleButton;
```

And now i want to add two buttons as the `rightBarButtonItems`:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.editButtonItem,self.aToZButton, nil];
```

And i noticed that this two things can't work together,if i add the `titleview` i only see one button in the right.

Any idea for any solution? other way to be able to click `UINavigationBar`?

Comment: If it is so, use button instead of title view. Add a custom barbutton item without any background, which may seem like label. :)

Comment: titlebutton is a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the frame of the titleButton that you have created. May be reducing it a bit may allow you to add two buttons.